# How to make Outlook "Attach File" always use default location

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-2010

I've done a fair amount of Googling on this and seem to be asking the opposite question to everyone else.

In Outlook 2010, how can I make "Attach File" always show the default location rather than showing the last location visited after the first time of use.

I have set the default location and this is shown when attaching a file the first time after opening up Outlook. I want Outlook to not remember where I've been in this instance. Closing Outlook and opening a new instance appears to be the only way to make it use the default location again.

In summary - How do you stop Outlook, and Office apps in general, remembering the last location visited?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted this question on the Microsoft Answers site and was informed that what I would like to achieve is impossible.
The closest functionality is to add the required location to the Favorites section of the navigation pane; requiring a single click.

Full answer [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/how-to-make-outlook-attach-file-always-use-default/3f4f9643-d1c3-4ebb-9a15-77f755e5f9fb?tm=1462437935261)